# How to combine 2 .mp4 videos on android device?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

The goal is to combine 2 .mp4 videos like one playing after the other. There are countless references to ffmpeg, which is not a very good option since it involves NDK making the project really heavy for some not so significant function.

I came to know that mediacodec has been improved a lot. I need a guide to help me through it. I couldn't find any.

**Also I am looking for combining .mp3 and a photo (single) and making a .mp4**

Please help.

I tried using javacv library for 2nd query, it was a dead end.
The code is as follows:

```
{FFmpegFrameGrabber videoFrames = FFmpegFrameGrabber.createDefault(videoSource);
    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(videoFile, 200,         200);
    recorder.setFrameRate(10);
    recorder.start();
    Frame frame = videoFrames.grab();
    for (int i = 0; i < (numSeconds * 10); i++) {
        recorder.record(frame);
    }
}
```

It takes 12 seconds just to make a 5 frame video. fps is 25.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to merge two video files the easy way is [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) (it has everything you need). The other way is to try to extract the audio and video channels with `MediaExtractor`, than use the `MediaMuxer` to merge the two files into one. Also, make sure the files are identical in terms of resolution, framerate and bitrate, otherwise the merge may not be perfect. In such case, you may need to re-encode the files. You can do that with `FFMPEG`, or you might want to consider sophisticated Android tools such as the `MediaCodec`.

**UPDATE:**

Creating an audio `.mp4` with a single frame should be the easiest in `FFMPEG`. If you need a lighter solution, you have to encode your image with `MediaCodec`, and extract the audio from the `.mp3` first. After that, you have to mux the given video and audio samples into a video file. You can find brilliant `MediaCodec` examples in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) and [BigFlake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)